# Creating an array with keys in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Currently I am working on a project, and what I am trying to do is to create an array with keys in razor.

That's what i have now:

```
string[] members = {@item.Name, @item.Url };
```

That's what I need:

```
string[] members = {pageName: @item.Name, pageUrl: @item.Url };
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't, you'll need a dictionary or anonymous object for that. Why do you need it though? There are probably better solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that you want an array and not a `dynamic`?. With a `dynamic` you can access specific properties, but you cannot iterate through it like an array.

Comment: I need to display JSON object on my page from Razor, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with arrays, however you can use a dictionary with string as keys.

```
Dictionary<string, string> member = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
     { "pageName", item.Name },
     { "pageUrl", item.Url }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display JSON object on my page from Razor [...]

You do not need an array for that. It sounds as you actually just want an object. You can create an object, and then render it as json.

```
@ {
    object members = new { pageName = @item.Name, pageUrl = @item.Url};
}

<script>
    var myObj = @Html.RenderAsJson(members); // With HtmlHelper.
    var myObj2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(members)) // Without HtmlHelper.
</script>
```

And a the helper method, if you prefer that option:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderAsJson(this HtmlHelper helper, object model)
    {
        var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
        return helper.Raw(obj);
    }
}
```

Now you got a javascript object called `myObj`. And you can access `myObj.pageName` from javascript.

Alternatively you can use `dynamic`, if you want to access the item in your view, but not in javascript.

```
@ {
    dynamic members = new { pageName = @item.Name, pageUrl = @item.Url};
}

<span>@members.pageName</span>
```